# Laravel 4.1 shared host weird behaviour

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am having troubles deploying Laravel to shared hosting. I have to point out that I have been doing this kind of deployment many times now and never encountered an error like this. This is some new hosting that my company is using and this is the first Laravel application ever on it so I gues the problem is with them.

Here is the error that I am getting:

https://www.premiumrewardsclub.com/new/

and heres the phpinfo:

https://www.premiumrewardsclub.com/phpinfo.php

The paths are all correct I think, otherwise I am getting the File not found error, but this is the third day of debugging this app so I am not 100% sure to rule out the paths error. Just saying.

I couldn't find anything useful after days of research on this error, so please if anyone has some clues about this, point me in some direction because I am out of ideas..

Thank you!

Edit: If thats of any help, I have come to conclusion that the application gets bootstrapped but dies here:

```
$framework = $app['path.base'].
                 '/vendor/laravel/framework/src';

require $framework.'/Illuminate/Foundation/start.php';
```

dd($app['path.base']); returns bool(false);

The strange thing about the return value of dd($app); is that it differs from the local dev machine by missing the "this" property from the object completely. Version of php on the dev machine is the same as one on the server.

Ideas?

Comment: have you done a `composer install`?

Comment: I did everything in local dev machine and uploaded to server, then changed the paths. This is the regular procedure that I usually do and had no problems with it until now.

Comment: okay what changes did you make to what file exactly? Add.: please remove /bootstrap/compiled.php and try again..

Comment: Changed paths in index.php and bootstrap/paths.php that is all. Changes are according to the paths to required files only, to match the paths to the files on the server.
Add: /bootstrap/compiled.php does not exist.. I have autoload.php, paths.php, start.php

Comment: Looks like the Application instance is getting `var_dump`ed. That certainly is not in the core. You probably forgot to remove `dd()` somewhere in your application code.

Comment: yes I am debugging atm, thats why. I removed it just now, have a look please. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you do not have php pear installed on your server.

Solution here: [Why "no such file or directory ... autoload.php" when accessing Laravel app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18407208/why-no-such-file-or-directory-autoload-php-when-accessing-laravel-app)

Comment: In the phpinfo link I provided there is this line:
include_path .:/usr/local/share/pear .:/usr/local/share/pear
 so I guess it is installed?

Comment: I think the issue is with pear because the errors on your site state so. http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.checking.php

Comment: yes, I think you are right. I have forwarded an email to my hosting company to fix this issue. As soon as I have a response I will get back to you. Thank you for the answer.