# fresh laravel framework installation on ubuntu 14.04 xamp server

Tags: php, laravel

I am in the `/opt/lamp/htdocs/lara` folder that was empty and cloned the `master` of Laravel from Github Download and do

```
sudo composer install
```

Then I was able to access `localhost/lara` but it brings down the lara directory. When I go ahead on to `localhost/lara/public` it brings up the error

```
Warning: require(/opt/lampp/htdocs/lara/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php):
     failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/lara/
bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/opt/lampp/htdocs/lara/bootstrap/../
vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/lara/
bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
```

How could I fix that?
After running the composer install the error changed to

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

and browse says internal server error

Comment: sorry for that one, composer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why "no such file or directory ... autoload.php" when accessing Laravel app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18407208/why-no-such-file-or-directory-autoload-php-when-accessing-laravel-app)

Comment: Do the permissions of the `vendor` folder allow your webserver-user access to it? Also you should set the DocumentRoot of that vhost to the `public` directory.

Comment: where is that ? how can change the vhost

Comment: **chmod 755** your vendor folder

Comment: just tried that but it doesn't seem to work,can you tell me where the vhost can be changed