# Error while running laravel application

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting the following error while running a laravel application "bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php : failed to open stream: No such file or directory". Please help.

Comment: Run the command "composer install"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why "no such file or directory ... autoload.php" when accessing Laravel app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18407208/why-no-such-file-or-directory-autoload-php-when-accessing-laravel-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must install the dependencies, run this command on the root of your project :

```
composer install
```